# Why does assignment with a pointer created using malloc cause segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please explain to me why using `malloc` here causes a seg fault at the specified line in `mystrncat()`? I was under the impression that I had access to elements of the heap across different stack frames. Is there any material I can look at to better understand this topic?

Thank You.

**EDIT:**

Here is my updated code, still segfault at the location.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define initial_malloc 20

char* mystrncat(char *dest, char *source, int n);

int main(void) {
    char *str1 = malloc(initial_malloc);
    char *str2 = malloc(initial_malloc);
    memset(str1, '\0', 20);
    memset(str2, '\0', 20);
    str1 = "hello";
    str2 = "World";

    mystrncat(str1, str2, 3);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *mystrncat(char *dest, char *source, int n) {
    int i, j, k, l;
    j = strlen(dest);
    for (i = 0; i < n && source[i] != '\0'; i++)
        ;
    for (k = j, l = 0; k < (j + i - 1); k++, l++) {
        dest[k] = source[l]; /* <-------runtime error here with malloc */
    }
    dest[k] = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: You need to put useful string data in your newly allocated memory. Currently it's not even zero terminated, let alone having the values "hello" and "world"

Comment: Because when you do `malloc` you don't initialize the strings with any sensible values, including the null-termination.

Comment: You can use `calloc(num, size)` and get zero-initialized memory.

Comment: The code as written (wiithout `malloc()`) is not valid either, since there's no space in `str1` to add any characters. If it doesn't crash, you're just being "lucky".

Comment: It's borked even without the malloc - UB because of extendiing 'str1' :(

Comment: The new code is broken because you overwrite the pointers with addresses of the string literals `"hello"` and `"world"`. This is not how you copy strings in C. Use `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` does not copy the string. It only assigns the poiner with the address (in your case) of the string literal. String literals are read only and any attempt of writing them usually ends in the SEGFAULT.

You need to copy (using the strcpy) the literal to the str1 and then you can concat them.

Second string (`str2`) is not needed at all here.

Use proper types (size_t) and try to be const correct

BTW your malloced memory here is lost.

A bit amended version

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define initial_malloc 20

char* mystrncat(char *, const char *, size_t);

int main(void) {
    char *str1 = malloc(initial_malloc);

    if(str1)
    {
        strcpy(str1, "hello");
        mystrncat(str1, "World", 3);
        printf("%s\n", str1);
        free(str1);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *mystrncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n) 
{
    char *SavedDest = dest;

    while(*dest++);
    dest--;
    while(n && *src)
    {
        *dest++ = *src++;
        n--;
    }
    *dest = 0;
    return SavedDest;
}
```

Comment: `while(*dest++);` is a tad inelegant, and `*dest = 0;` would be clearer as `*dest = '\0';` without any impact on performance.

Comment: @chqrlie it is maybe for not experienced programmers. `'\0'` in this case :D.

Comment: It is a matter of style. I personally would favor `while (*dest) continue;` and definitely `*dest = '\0';`.

Comment: Note also that your approach is not fully correct: `mystrncat(dest, NULL, 0)` would have undefined behavior. Since you favor compactness, I would suggest this fix: `while (n-- && *src) *dest++ = *src++;`

Comment: C standard functions do not check for the NULL pointers. You have to complain to standard library implementers :)

Comment: If `n` is `0`, no characters from `src` are appended to `dest`, so no characters should be read from `src`, hence a null pointer or one that points just past the end of an actual array should be OK.

Comment: @chqrlie no chars  are read from src - you are right the order should be reversed

Comment: The empty-statement semicolon is particularly confusing. At the very least, I'd change it to `while (*dest++) { /*intentionally empty*/ }`.

Comment: @aschepler I do not like your way. It is only question of taste.

Answer (score 2):

You change `str1` and `str2` just before you invoke `mystrncat` and make them point to string literals.  Attempting to modify the memory pointed to by `str1` has undefined behavior, in your case a segmentation fault.

Since you intend to initialize the allocated memory, use `calloc()` that will perform the initialization more efficiently and with the correct size. Your code does not use `initial_malloc`, so it will likely fail if `initial_malloc` is redefined to a different value.

You should output the resulting string to check for correctness.

Note also that your function `mystrncat` has different semantics from the standard function `strncat`. If this is your intent, the name `mystrncat` is misleading.

Here is a modified version with the standard semantics:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define initial_malloc 20

char *mystrncat(char *dest, const char *source, size_t n);

int main(void) {
    char *str1 = malloc(initial_malloc);
    char *str2 = malloc(initial_malloc);
    if (str1 == NULL || str2 == NULL) {
        printf("memory allocation failure\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    strcpy(str1, "hello");
    strcpy(str2, "World");
    mystrncat(str1, str2, 3);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    free(str1);
    free(str2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

char *mystrncat(char *dest, const char *source, size_t n) {
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = strlen(dest); i < n && source[i]; i++, j++) {
        dest[j] = source[i];
    }
    dest[j] = '\0';

    return dest;
}
```

Comment: rather inefficient `mystrncat` function https://godbolt.org/z/TDORBN

Comment: @P__J__: less of a difference with clang. Granted your version does not use `strlen` and I am flabbergasted that neither gcc nor clang inline `strlen` at `-O3`. My intent was to preserve the OP's approach, not to squeeze every bit of performance.

Comment: we should show the efficient way. Beginners tend to use indexes in the places they should not.

Comment: @P__J__: Did you benchmark both versions on a variety of test cases? It is not so obvious which would be more efficient from the assembly output. Index based accesses are mostly free on modern ALUs.

Comment: `for (i = 0, j = strlen(dest); i < n && source[i] != '\0'; i++, j++)` IMO in C most of the programmer do not compare to zero. `for (i = 0, j = strlen(dest); i < n && source[i]; i++, j++)` is IMO more C elegant